# Insert into newly created table - looping chain of synonyms

Tags: sql, oracle, dml

Its a simple insert to a newly created table

```
INSERT INTO my_table(id, d1, d2, d3)
VALUES (l_id, l_d1, l_2, l_d3);
```

and for some reason it results with error :

```
Error(165,21): PL/SQL: ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms
```

I see its quite oftenly mentioned error here on SO, but i've seen no similar scenario i could relate to, so i'm puzzled.
I made no synonims (as some in other posts suggest, selecting data from dba_synonyms results in one row). Maybe someone here could help ?

Comment: Who owns the synonym in DBA_SYNONYMS hit?  (My guess: PUBLIC).  Who owns the object it points to?  (My guess: not you).

Comment: same schema under which i created the table

Comment: How can you be the owner if, as you say, it's a newly created table and you haven't made any synonyms?

Comment: Is there any trigger defined on `my_table`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no, brand new table, maybe worth mentioning, i had to rename it once due to typo in the name..that seems banal but who knows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, i created ddl script, dropped the table and recreated it using the script and error was gone...